# Understanding seed phrase, private key, wallet addresses

Tags: cryptocurrency, seed

I have a question about Cryptocurrency wallets like Metamask (soft) or Ledger (hard).

How is a 12 or 24 word seed phrase enough to show the same crypto addresses in any crypto wallet that supports the same standard (ie. BIP-39).  Can someone unravel this for me / us?

Would it be this:

- seed phrase with its 2048^(12 or 24) combinations is used to encrypt a private key
- that private key can decrypt your list of addresses.  But if so, where is this list kept - a database, a blockchain (not sure how this would work)

I searched for some more information but I can only find more introductory articles.

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: One of the cryptocurrency-oriented stackexchanges, like the [bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) or [ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better place to ask about this. But the short answer is that the seed doesn't encrypt your keys, your keys and addresses are computed ("derived") from it. Same seed + same derivation process -> same keys. The keys and addresses *are* the wallet, so same keys&addresses -> same wallet. See [this](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets).

Comment: Ok thanks @GordonDavisson